# adding dynamic template to a Grid

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a view and am trying to use it for multiple scenarios, so i have to load my templates dynamically.
I have a Grid named `Content_Panel` and i would wish to add a `toolkit:LongListPicker` to it :

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector x:Name="_List" 
                          Background="Transparent" 
                          IsFlatList="True"   
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SmallImageTemplate}"
                          ListHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ListHeader}" 
                          ListFooterTemplate="{StaticResource ListFooter}" />
```

I would like to be able to add the templates name dynamically (so, acording to what variables i have on `onNavigatedTo` i can select the correct template. How can i do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't do it *just* like that. The easiest would be to switch the template, in C#, in your `OnNavigatedTo` event.

Something like:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("template"))
    {
        var template = NavigationContext.QueryString["template"];
        switch (template)
        {
            case "small"
                _List.ItemTemplate = Resources["SmallImageTemplate"] as ContentTemplate;
            case "big"
                _List.ItemTemplate = Resources["BigImageTemplate"] as ContentTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```